# HTTP request headers not in $_SERVER

Tags: php

I'm trying to get custom HTTP headers sent in a request.  PHP is running in CGI mode so they aren't available in `$_SERVER` and `getallheaders()` doesn't return them either.

Using rewrite rules as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php#74592 works fine, but is there some way to do this for *all* headers rather than having to write individual rewrite rules for each one?

e.g. currently have

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_MY_HEADER:%{HTTP:My-Header}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_MY_OTHER_HEADER:%{HTTP:My-Other-Header}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_MY_OTHER_OTHER_HEADER:%{HTTP:My-Other-Other-Header}]
```

etc etc

Comment: No, I don’t think that is possible; you explicitly have to name the env variables you want to read those values from, there is no wildcard-with-automatic-looping-over available in this context.